# How do I use slashdb with redshift database

Tags: slashdb

Is it possible to use slashdb with redshift? And if so, how can I create an instance on aws and choose the redshift database?

The pricing page mentions redshift, but nowhere else. The setup menu doesn't look like it shows redshift as an option in the videos

Answer (score 0):

Currently the pre-built AMIs and virtual machine images for SlashDB do not ship with Redshift support. SlashDB team can do a custom build for you, but you need to get in touch with us: https://www.slashdb.com/contact/